# MKOverlayView and OpenGL

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, mkmapview

I currently have a `UIView` that draws radar data on top of a `MKMapView` using OpenGL. Because of the level of detail in the radar image, OpenGL is required (CoreGraphics is not fast enough).

All of the images that I am drawing are saved in `MKMapPoints`.  I choose them over the standard `CLLocationCoordinate2D` because their lengths do not depend on the latitude. The basic method for drawing is this:

1. Add the `GLView` as a subview of the `MKMapView` and set `GLView.frame = MKMapView.frame`.
2. Using `GLOrthof`, set the projection of the `GLView` to equal the current visible `MKMapRect` of the map.  Here is the code that does this.

   ```
   CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateTopLeft =
       [mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)
                toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
   MKMapPoint pointTopLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateTopLeft);

   CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateBottomRight =
       [mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(mapView.frame.size.width,
                                         mapView.frame.size.height)
                toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
   MKMapPoint pointBottomRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateBottomRight);

   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrthof(pointTopLeft.x, pointBottomRight.x,
            pointBottomRight.y, pointTopLeft.y, -1, 1);
   ```
3. Set the viewport to be the correct size using `glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight)` where `backingWidth` and `backingHeight` is the size of the `mapView` in points.
4. Draw using `glDrawArrays`.  Not sure if this matters, but `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` and `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` are both enabled during the draw.

Using this method, everything works fine.  The drawing is performed like it is supposed to.  The only problem is since it is a subview of the `mapView` (and not an overlay), the radar image is drawn on top of any other `MKAnnotations` and `MKOverlays`.  I need this layer to be drawn under the other annotations and overlays.

What I tried to do to get this working was to make the `glView` a subview of a custom `MKOverlayView` instead of the `mapView`.  What I did was give the `MKOverlay` a `boundingMapRect` of `MKMapRectWorld` and set the frame of the `glView` the same way that I set the projection (since frame of a `MKOverlayView` is determined by `MKMapPoints` and not `CGPoints`).  Again, here is the code.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateTopLeft =
    [mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)
             toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
MKMapPoint pointTopLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateTopLeft);

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateBottomRight =
    [mapView convertPoint:CGPointMake(mapView.frame.size.width,
                                      mapView.frame.size.height)
             toCoordinateFromView:mapView];
MKMapPoint pointBottomRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinateBottomRight);

glRadarView.frame = CGRectMake(pointTopLeft.x, pointTopLeft.y,
                               pointBottomRight.x - pointTopLeft.x,
                               pointBottomRight.y - pointTopLeft.y);
```

When I do this, the `glView` is positioned correctly on the screen (in the same place that is was while it was a subview of the `mapView`), but the drawing no longer works correctly.  When the image does come up, it is not the right size and not in the correct location.  I did a check and `backingWidth` and `backingHeight` are still the size of the view in points (as they should be).

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Are you sure you need to render the radar in real-time? Is prerendering (e.g. one included PNG for every frame) not an option?

Comment: Short answer, no. There are some things I am doing with the data (and more I plan on doing in updates) where a prerendered image won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been away from iphone for too long to really fully grok your code, but I seem to recall from when I messed with Open GL on the iPhone some time ago, I found that it was necessary to maintain my own z-Index and simply draw items in that order... Each draw operation happened rotated in 3d properly, but something drawn later was always on top of something drawn earlier. One of my early test programs drew a grid on a surface, and then caused the whole thing to flip. My expectation was that the grid would disappear when the back of the object was facing me, but it remained visible because it was drawn later in a separate operation (IIRC)

It's possible that I was doing something wrong that caused that problem, but my solution was to order my draws by a z index.

Can you draw the image first using your first method?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I am only drawing one thing, and it is a 2D drawing.

Comment: So perhaps you need to be drawing 2 things... Perhaps you could put a texture (with the radar) on a rectangle the size of the screen? http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html ... Then you can draw them in the order you want.

Comment: That's what I am doing now and it works. The part I am having trouble with is encapsulating that into a MKOverlayView.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should just set the viewport before setting the projection mode.

Comment: That does not seem to be working either. I tried having it before directly before glLoadIdentity() and between glLoadIdentity() and glOrthof().